# How to reach edit event in Calendar through programmatical code?

Tags: java, android, calendar

How to reach edit event in Calendar through programmatical code?
Any help is highly appreciated and thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: Please see [this][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564530/how-to-edit-the-calender-events-via-android-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this intent you may get solution:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
intent.putExtra("title", "Some title");
intent.putExtra("description", "Some description");
intent.putExtra("beginTime",  cal.getTimeInMillis());
intent.putExtra("endTime",  cal.getTimeInMillis()+60*60*1000);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial describes how to access the internal calendar database inside Google Android applications:
http://jimblackler.net/blog/?p=151

Comment: Since the code must be version independant, We cannot use different code for various type of phone and versions. We have to get Uri from calendar database according to version. The link u specified was version dependant